# React Component DidMount not called when refresh the Page

Tags: reactjs, flux

I have developed the Component it's look like,

```
 var ManageViewPage = React.createClass({
  // Get initial state from stores
  getInitialState: function() {
    return setViewData();
  },
  componentDidMount: function() {
    SystemMetaItemStore.CallSystemMetaItem("Views");
    ItemStore.addChangeListener(this._onChange);
    SystemMetaItemStore.addChangeListener(this._onChange);
      alert("Did mount");
  },
  // Remove change listers from stores
  componentWillUnmount: function() {
    ItemStore.removeChangeListener(this._onChange);
    SystemMetaItemStore.removeChangeListener(this._onChange);
    alert("Did Unmount");
  },


  preventDefault: function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
  },
  DeleteViewclick:function(event)
  {

  },
  render: function() {
    return (
      <div className="row">

      </div>
)
},

_onChange: function() {
  this.setState(setViewData());
}

});
module.exports =ManageViewPage;
```

When I will call this page first time using routing then it will call the alert "did mount" but when I press F5 to refresh the browser it will not called the alert "did mount" so can anyone guide me what I did wrong here ?

Comment: so when you refresh does did unmount pop? if no thats your answer.

Comment: ya at the time of refresh did unmount not pop up so you mean to say  browser refresh is not working with react ?

Comment: i mean, the component is not destroyed. so on next refresh, it will not run with didMount cycle.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Rebuild ReactJs Component](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35363569/rebuild-reactjs-component)