# Rebuild ReactJs Component

Tags: reactjs, components, mount, rebuild

I have a reactjs component(compA) in my app that call another reactjs component(compB) to mount compA.

Inside compB, I have a button that, in function "componentDidUpdate" I need to destroy and rebuild compA.

Anybody has idea how to do this?

---

The approximate code is this, but, in my code compA and B they are in different files.

```js
use strict';

var CompA = React.createClass({
    getDefaultProps: function() {
        return {
            name: 'location',
        }
    },
    render: function () {
        return <CompB name={this.props.name}/>;
    }
});

var CompB = React.createClass({
    getDefaultProps: function() {
        return {
            name: 'select'
        }
    },
    componentDidUpdate: function() {
        $('.button').click(function() {
            /*
             * RELOAD HERE COMPONENT
             */
        });
    },
    render: function () {
        return <div><select name={this.props.name}><option value="x">X</option><option value="y">Y</option></select><button id="button">Reload</button></div>
    }
});

ReactDOM.render(<CompA />, document.getElementsByID("compA"));
```

```html
<html>
<body>
  <div id="compA"></div>

  <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://fb.me/react-0.14.7.js"></script>
  <script src="https://fb.me/react-dom-0.14.7.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-core/5.8.23/browser.min.js"></script>

  <script src="comp.jsx" type="text/jsx"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: If I understood your answer correctly, you can use in this case `setState` that triggers re-render https://jsfiddle.net/_alexander_/69z2wepo/31153. Or you can use `.forceUpdate` https://jsfiddle.net/_alexander_/69z2wepo/31154/

Comment: I go analise and I give the feedback to you!

Comment: @Alexander don't is this yet. I have some particulars that I do not put in the code. 1) I have one more componente to create the button and select, 1 level more. 2) For select mount I use ajax.

Comment: could you clarify what do you want to get in result?

Comment: @Alexander Ok, lets go! I did make in my app with a component for my selec. I created 3 react components. 

The first, set info that for ajax, how url, name of select;
The second, call the ajax require;
The third, mount the html element (<select ... /> )

In my app, I did need to construct a cache. With this I need to reload the ajax call. And repopulate my select.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't rebuild an entire CompA from CompB, but calling setState from CompB will rebuild CompB and, in your case, the entire CompA (because you do not have anything else inside it).

If you want to rebuild a component from an Ajax source, you can have a look at: 
[React Js: How to reload the initila data loaded via ajax?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33482648/react-js-how-to-reload-the-initila-data-loaded-via-ajax)

Comment: Perfect! Resolved my problem with ajust of code! Tnks!